# The difference between state and status

Tags: meaning

According to different dictionaries, *state* and *status* have different meanings.

However, is there any case they could have the same meaning? For example:

1. The state of the situation is not clear
2. The status of the situation is not clear

Comment: Welcome to the ELU Stack Exchange Hattan! Go ahead and include the research you've already done, like providing the relevant definitions you've found. And here is the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) for the site.

Answer (score 6):

They are similar - both talk *about* the situation, but to my ear, *status* is more 'meta' than *state*.

> **state** *noun*
> 1 The particular condition that someone or something is in at a specific time.
> ‘the state of the company's finances’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/state)
>
> **status** *noun*
> 2 The situation at a particular time during a process.
> ‘an update on the status of the bill’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/status)

In both cases, the state/status is a condition of sorts, and there can be considerable semantic overlap. However, consider swapping the terms in the examples: *status of the company's finances* and *state of the bill*. Let's work this through by looking at a few quotes, using *finances* as the point of comparison.

*State* tends to refer to the finances on its own merits while *status* tends to relate to a classification of the finances for some external purpose.

> if my view of the *state* of the Company's finances be correct, the whole or the greater part of the other items must have been furnished from the territorial revenues.
> [- Reports from the Select Committee[s] of the House of Commons ..., Volume 1](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Wm9UAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA2-PA716&lpg=RA2-PA716&dq=%22the%20state%20of%20the%20company%27s%20finances%22&source=bl&ots=LU9gD6OHuc&sig=lrAfD6fUS84qOczCAYE-rfxRezA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFmKesq7rcAhUCQN4KHcIdAj0Q6AEIPzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20state%20of%20the%20company%27s%20finances%22&f=false)
>
> Factory owners ... spent more than $100,000 restoring their financial status.
> [- ABC News](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2018-07-25/antonio-datillo-sentenced-perverting-justice-perjury/10032794)

Spending money would worsen the *state* of finances (its financial worth). However, if it costs money to, say, properly audit the financials so that the ratings authorities would grant a better classification (e.g. AA instead of BB), then spending money could be said to improve someone's financial *status*.

Here are some examples of questions and answers to illustrate the position I'm articulating:

- What is the *state* of the company's finances? They are in good shape.
- What is the *status* of the company's finances? They have a AAA rating.

In your examples, if the *state* of the situation is unclear, it is the situation itself that is uncertain; if the *status* of the situation is unclear, the situation might be very well understood, but its assigned rank is unclear.

Nevertheless, to your specific question about whether it is *possible* for the *state* and *status* of something to refer to the same thing - yes, it is. For example, a *status report* reports on the *state* of a situation.

> **status report** *noun*
> A report describing the current situation with regard to a business, project, matter, etc., especially one in a series of such reports summarizing a changing state of affairs.
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/status_report)